# Specifying MySQL user hosts with IPv6 addresses

Tags: mysql, security

Inspired after making the move to IPv6 on my MySQL server, and intrigued by the lack of documentation regarding 'user'@'[IPv6]' nomenclature I proceeded to discover how to limit my users based on their IPv6 address.

My allocation is a /56 and so I wanted to limit my DB users to this prefix length.  My test host was `2001:DB8:111:6601::a01:120`

The following didn't work at all:

```
2001:DB8:111:6600::
2001:DB8:111:6600::%
2001:DB8:111:6601::
2001:DB8:111:66%::
2001:DB8:0111:6601::%
2001:DB8:111:6600::/56
2001:DB8:111:6601::a01:120/56
2001:DB8:111:6601:0:0:a01:120/56
2001:DB8:111:6601::a01:120/128
2001:DB8:111:6601::/64
2001:DB8:111:6601::%/128
2001:DB8:111:6601::%/1
2001:DB8:111:6601::%/64
2001:DB8:111:6601::a01:0120
```

The following worked

```
2001:DB8:111:6601::% (too limiting as it's a /64, not /56)
2001:DB8:111:6601::a01:120 (too limiting as it's a host)
2001:DB8:111:66%::% (but may match 066x in the 7th and 8th bytes)
2001:DB8:111:66__::% (this appears to be the best fit)
```

Some notes:

- don't use leading zeros in fields
- don't bother with /prefixlen

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, I don't have definite answers, but these seem likely:)

`::` is shorthand for any number of `0000` segments so as to end up with 8 groups.  So, `::%` is ill-defined.

`%` is the wildcard available in MySQL, not `_`.

Perhaps `%` is only applicable for a 16-bit chunk, not part of such.

With ipv4, a mask is given using `/`.  Example:  `198.51.100.0/255.255.255.0: Any host on the 198.51.100 class C network`.  I suspect that ipv6 would be similar.  -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/account-names.html

So, I would guess

```
2001:DB8:111:6600::/FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FF00::
```

Comment: Underscore `_` is definitely a wildcard that can be used in hostnames.  From the manual: _The `%` and `_` wildcard characters are permitted in host name or IP address values. These have the same meaning as for pattern-matching operations performed with the LIKE operator_